# cucumber regex statements for java

Tags: java, cucumber

I code cucumber scripts for java

There is a following case for or selection

```
working  @When("^(chrome|firefox|edge) browser started")

don't work @When("(chrome|firefox|edge) browser started")
```

Also, I don't understand function of ^ char, because

```
don't work @When("^browser")    => feature    when browser started  
working @When("^browser started")    => feature    when browser started  
working @When("browser started")    => feature    when browser started
```

Comment: The `^` anchor just means "at the very start of the string."  If you _omit_ it, the pattern might still work, because by default the search will start from the beginning on the string anyway.

Comment: In first case, for or statement, when it works with ^ car but it doesn't work without ^, I don't understand this logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cucumber supports two types of expressions which are mutually exclusive:

- regular expressions (aka RegEx)
- Cucumber expressions

Cucumber distinguishes which sort of expressions you are using with checking "anchors" symbols which for RegEx have to be `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the string.

So while the syntax in your first example is valid for RegEx, it is working. But if your expressions misses anchors (like in your second example) it is treated as "Cucumber Expression" where that `(chrome|firefox|edge)` is not valid any more.

For cucumber expressions to work with your case you have to apply "Custom Pameter Types".

See details at [cucumber github page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions).